# Remove and add protection within onEdit script

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

## CURRENT SITUATION

As an owner I've created a spreadsheet that makes an editor of everyone who has received the link. However there are some partially protected sheets with a few unprotected columns, making it possible for these editors to change values. I have an `onEdit` function that automatically sorts the entire range of a sheet when a cell has been edited by user.

### PROBLEM

Unfortunately, since these sheets are partially protected, the `AUTOSORT` does not work. I need to add something to the script so that when the `onEdit` is triggered, the activesheet becomes unprotected and the AUTOSORT can do its job. After that the protection is added again (with a few columns as an exception). I don't want everyone to lose their editors rights after this. So it needs to go back to normal.

### Script that I tried so far but not working:

```
function onEdit() {

if (e.range.columnStart == 3 && e.range.getValue() != '') {
var sheets = ["FASHION NL", "FASHION BE","KIDS & UNDERWEAR BNL" ,"NEW BUSINESS BNL" ,"SPORTS & SHOES BNL", "HD&E BNL"]; // Please set your expected sheet names.
var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
if (sheets.includes(sheet.getSheetName())) {
var range = sheet.getRange("A5:bY600");

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var allProtections = 
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET);
var protection = allProtections[0];
protection.remove();

range.sort({ column: 11, ascending: true });
e.source.toast('Sort complete.');
    }
  }
var protection = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().protect();
protection.setUnprotectedRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('AK:AK'), 
spreadsheet.getRange('BN:BN')])
var editors = SpreadSheet.getEditors();
for (var i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
SpreadSheet.removeEditor(editors[i])
     }
}
```

### CLARIFICATION PROBLEM

It does not give me an error, but script fails to sort the data range.

### SAMPLE SHEET STRUCTURE

Trigger is on column C (3)

Script is created in a way that it reflects whether the Activesheet where the edit takes place is one of the predetermined range of sheets.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a sample of your sheet's structure? And how is the code failing? Is it not doing anything or are you getting an error?

Comment: @Daniel, I have updated my question based on your comment...

Answer (score 1):

You should keep all your permissions as they're and set the function as if it's run by yourself (delete all the parts that have to do with removing and adding permissions). Call it other way than onEdit, for example autoSort(), and set an installable trigger run by event. You can read about it [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

The sorting then would be run as it was done by you but triggered by other users' changes. Give it a try and let me know!

Comment: Ah okay, but then the “if” rules of the onEdit function would still apply? I configured it in such a way that the onEdit function only works when a certain cell in a certain sheet is changed.

Comment: Yes, they'll work!

Comment: Great, I think it will work.. thanks!